# export default function with sapper json route

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, sapper

Starting from the [sapper official template](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper-template/blob/c0ca291dc23eb8f565923bb1ef4b5fd3a9cc75f7/src/routes/blog/index.json.js#L10), I want to use `export default` as suggested eslint:

```
export default function get(_, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  });

  res.end(contents);
}
```

I have the following error:

```
invalid json response body at http://127.0.0.1:3000/blog.json reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

FetchError: invalid json response body at http://127.0.0.1:3000/blog.json reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at eval (webpack:///./src/node_modules/@sapper/server.mjs?:785:32)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

And everything works as expected if I remove the `default` keyword.

Is that an eslint bug and I should not use the `default` keyword here, or is it something wrong with my change?

Comment: How are you importing this function?

Comment: I clearly don't know. This is handle by the Sapper server.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `default` keyword here. You could turn off that rule for eslint or ignore it for this particular case. ESLint is not made specifically for Sapper, so it is best to go with the Sapper docs over ESLint rules when they conflict.